# Intermittent aborted connections, when Web Scraping using WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient, streamreader

Sometimes i get error, and sometimes i get data from site

Error:

```
Wyjątek nieobsłużony: System.Net.WebException: Żądanie zostało przerwane: Połączenie zostało nieoczekiwanie zakończone.
       w System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       w System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
       w System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
       w ConsoleApplication3.Download.getUrlData() w c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual
    Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:wiersz 4
    1
       w ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args) w c:\Users\user\Documents\V
    isual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\Program.cs:wi
    ersz 55
```

English Translation:
The request was aborted: The connection was unexpectedly terminated

My code:

```
 public string getUrlData()
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Random r = new Random();
            //Random IP Address
            client.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] = r.Next(0, 255) + "." + r.Next(0, 255) + "." + r.Next(0, 255) + "." + r.Next(0, 255);
            //Random User-Agent
            client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/" + r.Next(3, 5) + ".0 (Windows NT " + r.Next(3, 5) + "." + r.Next(0, 2) + "; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/" + r.Next(3, 5) + "." + r.Next(0, 5) + "." + r.Next(0, 5);
            Stream datastream = client.OpenRead(Url);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                sb.Append(reader.ReadLine());
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

And the main:

```
var d = new Download("http://wiocha.pl");

            var str = d.getUrlData();

            Console.WriteLine(str);
```

what to do to get the data every time without error?

Comment: Please post the full error including the actual exception message and exception type

Comment: I edit and paste full error code

Comment: Looks like the server cut the connection. At least that's what the message says. It looks like you are scraping some site and the site is not cooperating, maybe they shut down mass requests.

Answer (score 0):

**Limit on Max Conncurrent Clients**

I know this is a limitation for HttpWebRequest: you can only have 1 or 2 active client requests at a time. I am not familiar with the WebClient way, but you must actively dispose of the HttpWebResponse object when using the HttpWebRequest way. Therefore, I suggest you first try disposing the datastream before returning that string.

**Not your programming**

It looks like you are web scraping, and they are cutting you off. You will need to:

1. Limit how often you send requests, and;
2. Vary your source IP using other machines/networks with different IPs and/or use of VPNs.

**Another improvement**

Also, you there's an easier way to get the input stream into a single string: `var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();`. So you wouldn't need the StringBuilder or the While loop.